# How do I download Ubuntu for phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am wondering how do i download ubuntu for the google nexus 5, and have they released an official os yet or is it still the beta?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install for the details. I think there is no an "official" release. Even I can't find the Nexus 5 among the [working devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).